# Applying best practice to make js file for data access in node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, node-mssql

I created file which I am going to use to keep only data access inside:

```
    const sql = require('mssql');

        async function getUsers(config) {
          try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(config);

            return await pool.request().query('select * from someTable');
          } catch (err) {}
        }

        async function getRoles(config) { ...
        async function updateUser(config) { ...

module.export([
  getUsers,
  getRoles,
  updateUser
])
```

All this functions are in one js file and you can see each function receive config object as parameter.
I am trying to avoid this and have one pool.
But this file is not class it doesn't have constructor or init.
And this is aws lambda project in index.js I get config data this is why I am passing config to each function.
How I can make this file so I can pass config once and make sure connections are closed?
I am confused on how to organise this file using some best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Since all those functions are in one JS class, and using the same SQL client object, you can just instantiate the sql client outside of the functions, and with using closures, your functions can access that sql client.

For example:

```
    // sql_scripts.js
    const sql = require('mssql');

 const sql_client = async (config) => {
    const _sql_client = await sql.connect(config);

    const getUsers = async () => { 
      try {
           const res =  await _sql_client.request().query('select * from someTable');
           _sql_client.close_connection() // always run a close connection
          return res
      } catch (err) {}
        function
     }

    const getRoles = async () => {
    ....
    }
}

module.exports = sql_client
```

Then you can create an instance of sql_client via calling :

```
const my_sql_client = sql_client(config)

my_sql_client.getUsers();
```

Comment: But shouldn't I close sql connection at some point. And to make pool I need config which is coming from parent file in this data access file I can't get that config.

Comment: See my updated answer, would something like this work?